# Sprite Kit: Contact detected but cannot get code to work for contact between two specific nodes

Tags: sprite-kit

I have defined a contact category bitmask:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t, ContactCategory) {
    ContactCategoryPenguin  = 1 << 0,
    ContactCategoryFish     = 1 << 1,
    ContactCategoryObstacle = 1 << 2,
    ContactCategoryBaddy    = 1 << 3
};
```

I have set up physics bodies for two objects:

```
// Penguin physics

-(void)setUpPhysicsBody {
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ContactCategoryPenguin;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ContactCategoryObstacle;
    ...
}

// Background physics

-(void)setUpBackground {
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
    background.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ContactCategoryObstacle;
    background.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ContactCategoryPenguin;
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    background.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    ...
    [self addChild:background];
}
```

And I have assigned the scene as an `<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>`, checking for contact as follows:

```
-(void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    NSLog(@"Contact!");
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask ) {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if ( firstBody.categoryBitMask == ContactCategoryPenguin && secondBody.categoryBitMask == ContactCategoryObstacle) {
        NSLog(@"Success if this gets called!");
    }
}
```

My first log gets printed. However, the second log does not. So I know that contact is being detected but the final conditional statement isn't doing what I think it should.

Urgh!

My hunch is that I've set the physics bodies up wrong. But the problem isn't clear to me. I've specified `skView.showsPhysics = YES;` and the physics bodies look right to me.

Any advice on why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is another, and slightly easier, way of dealing with contacts:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (ContactCategoryPenguin | ContactCategoryFish)) {
        NSLog(@"Penguin and fish made contact...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, the code within the conditional statement still isn't firing.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the method that I used for my own sprite-kit game. It should work fine.

```
enum CollisionMask: UInt32 {
case monster = 1
case star = 2
case endPoint = 4
case waypoint = 8
}

    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody  = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB
    var sprite: SKSpriteNode!
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionMask.monster.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == CollisionMask.star.rawValue {
            starContact(secondBody.node!)
            currentStar += 1

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A new day. Feeling less tired. The problem is obvious:

```
// Background physics

-(void)setUpBackground {
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
    background.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ContactCategoryObstacle;
    background.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ContactCategoryPenguin;
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    background.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    ...
    [self addChild:background];
}
```

I was setting the properties of the background's physics body before I'd created it. Correct code should be:

```
// Background physics

-(void)setUpBackground {
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
    background.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    background.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ContactCategoryObstacle;
    background.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ContactCategoryPenguin;
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    ...
    [self addChild:background];
}
```